# Where is debugdraw for Box2djs

Tags: javascript, box2d

I can't seem to find the debugdraw for Box2djs. Did I miss something or is just not implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different port of Box2d for javascript. [Box2dJs](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) doesn't have debugdraw in the api. However, [Box2dWeb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) does have it.